# Deploy an application made in Node js by Azure functions or Web Apps

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

i have a simple application made in Node.js is a simple express backend server with nodemailer to send messages, the problem is that i mount an application in Azure with a web app and the deploy sucessfull is good, but the link that azure provides to me doesnt work, can someone help me to understand what is happen?

Deploy successfull
Deploy an web app in Azure

Comment: Can you please share the code which you have tried?  and   Could you please share the Error which you got?

Comment: Can you also check, that you are not specifying the PORT explicitly in the Code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- `npm install express nodemailer` package have been installed.

**code:**

```
const express = require('express');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = 3001; // Change this to your desired port

// Middleware to parse JSON and form data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Serve static files (optional)
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Basic HTML form to collect email details
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`
    <form action="/send" method="post">
      <input type="email" name="to" placeholder="Recipient Email">
      <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Email Subject">
      <textarea name="message" placeholder="Email Message"></textarea>
      <button type="submit">Send Email</button>
    </form>
  `);
});

// Handle email sending
app.post('/send', async (req, res) => {
  const { to, subject, message } = req.body;

  // Create a Nodemailer transporter
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'your-gmail', // Your Gmail email address
      pass: 'Your gmail password', // Your Gmail password
    },
  });

  // Email message
  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'your-gmail',
    to,
    subject,
    text: message,
  };

  // Send email
  try {
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log('Email sent successfully:', mailOptions);
    res.send('Email sent successfully!');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Error sending email.');
  }
});

// Start the Express server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

For authentication, give the correct Gmail email-id and password.
The above code works fine. Check like below:

[image]

[image]

I have created a web app service in the Azure portal with the Node.js runtime environment.

[image]

I deployed the application into the web app successfully.
check like below.

[image]

When I access the Web app URL, I get the expected result in the browser.
Check like below:

[image]